# ¿Cómo concectar Spring MVC (Servirdor) con jquery mobile(cliente)?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, programación-móvil

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil con Jquery Mobile, ya he hecho la aplicación del lado del servidor con Spring MVC e Hibernate, tengo las interfaces de los Dao los Servicios con sus respectivas implementaciones y los controladores.
Ahora lo que deseo saber como conectarlo con una interfaz de usuario con Jquery Mobile(por ejemplo desde un dispositivo móvil). He creado unas interfaces de usuario para el cliente en el mismo proyecto donde he creado la aplicación del lado del servidor y funciona muy bien, y lo que quiero hacer es tener por un lado la aplicación para el servidor y en otro proyecto otra aplicación para el cliente (desde un dispositivo móvil, un .apk) pero que se conecte con la aplicación del servidor. ¿Que tecnologías podría utilizar?. Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.
Aquí algo de código de mi controlador de usuario.

```
 
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {
@Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/postusuario", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertarUsuario(@ModelAttribute(value = "usuario") Usuarios usuario ){
        usuarioService.insertarUsuario(usuario);
        return "redirect:usuarioslist";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/editarusuario", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editarUsuario(@RequestParam(value = "id") int idUsuario, Model model) {
        Usuarios usuario = usuarioService.obtenerUsuario(idUsuario);
        model.addAttribute("editusuario", usuario);
        return "usuarios/editar";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateusuario", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String actualizarUsuario(@ModelAttribute(value = "usuario") Usuarios usuario) {
        usuarioService.actualizarUsuario(usuario);
        return "redirect:usuarioslist";
    }
}
```

Las vistas las hice en .jsp en el mismo proyecto

Comment: ¿Qué clase/tipo de aplicación te imaginas tener del lado cliente? ¿Un sitio web responsivo? ¿Una aplicación hibrida (hecha con por ej.:Apache Cordova o PhoneGap)?

Comment: Gracias por responder, si puse que tipo de aplicación para el cliente (dispositivo móvil). Una aplicación para crear un apk para que funcione en un dispositivo móvil.

Comment: ¿Aplicación Android? ¿O quieres también poder instalarla en otro tipo de dispositivo móvil (ej: Windows Phone, Blackberry, iPhone)?

Comment: Por ahora solo Andriod, es por eso que puse .apk

Comment: Por lo que sé jQuery Mobile es para hacer sitios web responsivos, no aplicaciones nativas. Además de una aplicación nativa, puedes desarrollar para Android usando algún framework, en este [link](http://www.elandroidelibre.com/2015/10/los-mejores-frameworks-para-desarrolladores-android.html) hay una lista no exhaustiva. Toma uno y prueba hacer un tutorial.
A nivel backend se suelen armar APIs REST para comunicarse con los clientes ([aquí](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=rest+api+con+spring&tbs=lr:lang_1es&lr=lang_es) una búsqueda de tutoriales usando Spring), aunque no es la única manera.

Comment: Había visto en algún vídeo donde hacían una app para android usando jquery mobile (no recuerdo la url del vídeo) y se podía comunicar con algún servidor, pero no sabia que tecnologías utilizaban. es por eso que pregunté que tecnologías utilizar.

Comment: Hola como te comentaron JQueryMobile es para paginas web que se utilizan en celular. :) Pero la recomendación sería trabajarla tipo API, para que puedes ocupar cualquier cosa haciendo solo peticiones HTTP. YA sea Ionic, Appcelerator, Android o iOS

Comment: Gracias por responder @elporfirio. cuando te refieres a trabajarla tipo API, ¿te refieres a crear servicios Rest con Spring MVC? y usar ajax, json desde la aplicación jquery mobile o alguna otra de las que mencionas? Encontré un vídeo en youtube, pensaba en algo como esto.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqxbfwXDgkA

Comment: Si unos servicios Rest, para que solo devuelvas JSON . Porque ahora lo que devuelves son vistas :P lo cual no es muy adecuado pues después de escribir la vista tienes que hacer que JS las evalue para agregar la interacción. ES un buen tema para investigar :D

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas... Tengo ideas vagando por mi cabeza, las ordenaré e intentaré realizarlas, si presento inconvenientes al realizarlas regresaré por aquí con algunas preguntas. Gracias. Otra cosa, como podría crear un API REST con SPRING MVC. Algún manual, tutorial, libro seria de mucha utilidad y de gran ayuda, estaré gratamente agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacer un apk seria solo para Android por lo que no veo la necesidad de usar jQuery en ese caso.

Tienes 2 opciones:

**1:** Usar una aplicación web con jQuery, Angularjs, React o incluso puro Jsp con Spring, que va funcionar no solo para Android si no también para cualquier dispositivo que tenga un navegador de internet.

**2:** Utilizar código nativo en Java para Android con el que si vas a poder generar el .apk y funcionaria solo para Android y despues consumir tus APIs creadas con Spring MVC.

Ambas tienen sus ventajas y desventajas.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Gemasoft. Leí que con phonegap se podían crear .apk a partir de código html, css y js. y pues mi duda esta en que si podría implementar la aplicación cliente con jquery mobile y utilizar ajax, json y de esta manera consumir las APIs que crearia con Spring MVC. Encontré un video en youtube, dejo el link, pensaba en algo asi a lo del vídeo, mi duda es si se podrá implementar esto para lo que menciono en mi pregunta. Todo esto es para un trabajo de investigacion con jquery mobile y otros mas como Sencha Touch entre otros. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqxbfwXDgkA

Comment: Te sugiero checar tambien: ionic y react native.